# Javascript produces error on event.clientX

Tags: javascript

The program that I am building is a program that when the mouse is down, it reads mouse X and mouse Y positions. The code that produces the error is below:

```
function updateLocation(event) {
    setTimeout(function(event){
        var X = event.clientX;
        var Y = event.clientY;
    },300);
}
```

chrome, opera, firefox, and edge all say "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined(…)" what I don't understand is even if I copied the source code for `event.clientX` from w3schools.com, It still produces that error. I have tried rewriting the code, I have tried only passing `event` to `setTimeout()` or only to the function, but nothing works. can someon please help me, it's getting frustrating.

Here is a list of all the things that I tried:

```
function updateLocation(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var X = event.clientX;
        var Y = event.clientY;
    },300);
}
```

---

```
function updateLocation() {
    setTimeout(function(event){
        var X = event.clientX;
        var Y = event.clientY;
    },300);
}
```

---

```
function updateLocation(event) {
    alert(event.clientX);
}
```

---

```
function updateLocation(event) {
    setTimeout(function(event){
        var X = event.windowX;
        var Y = event.windowY;
    },300);
}
```

---

```
function updateLocation(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var X = event.windowX;
        var Y = event.windowY;
    },300);
}
```

---

```
function updateLocation() {
    setTimeout(function(event){
        var X = event.windowX;
        var Y = event.windowY;
    },300);
}
```

Comment: Show how you call the function.  Based on your description `event` is `undefined`.

Comment: Please check the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` callback function should not be having any argument since no parameters will be passed when it gets fired. That's why its getting as undefined.

If you just remove it from the function as below, it will work as you expected.

You can have a look at the below code.

```js
function updateLocation(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var X = event.clientX;
        var Y = event.clientY;
      console.log(X + ', ' + Y);
    },300);
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onmousedown="updateLocation(event)">Test Div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I bring bad news, it didn't work, as I expected. I have also tried calling the same function without the setTimeout method with an alert, displaying event.clientX, It produces that error no matter what, basically...

Comment: @Jacob can you update your question with the code whatever you tried, I will check all of them?

Comment: Also, I used a library computer to execute that code and it didn't work either, so there must be a syntax error or I am doing something incorrectly. The last program that I used this line on however, worked.